# Flow multi-column elements left-right before top-down

Tags: css

Is this possible?

So if we had a list:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

Instead of

Item 1   Item 3

Item 2   Item 4

We'd want

Item 1   Item 2

Item 3   Item 4

Is this possible with the multi-column layout module or am I better off doing this with old fashioned floats or inline divs?

Comment: I'd certainly go for floats in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<style>
  ul {list-style: none;}
  li {float: left;}
  li:nth-child(2n+1) {clear: left;} /* 1st of every twos */
</style>
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That certainly works, but I was hoping for a property in the multi-column module to make it work instead of using floats.

Comment: What if elements are of different heights and they can even be resized? Something like Google+ cards. Floats in this case won't work. Masonry would work, but resizing poses a completely different problem because all elements are absolutely positioned.