# Angular flex-layout dynamic row height

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

Can we have layout as below image with the help of [angular flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)?  Something similar is there with AngularJS - [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/card)

[image: expected behaviour]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the grid list from material: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview
But I think you are looking for a more dynamical approach, where you do not have to define the height yourself. This kind of layout is called "masonry layout" and can be achieved with plain css like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="masonry-layout">
  <div class="masonry-layout__panel" *ngFor="let option of options">
    <div class="masonry-layout__panel-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.masonry-layout {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0;
    margin: 8px;
}

.masonry-layout__panel {
    break-inside: avoid;
}

.masonry-layout__panel-content {
    padding: 8px;
    display: flex;
}
```

As an alternative, you can do it with the FlexLayoutModule, and define columns like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div class="column" fxFlex="50%>
    <div class="card">
    <div>
    <div class="card">
    <div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" fxFlex="50%>
    <div class="card">
    <div>
    <div class="card">
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the first solution is giving close result to what I want. But I wanted to make columns flow from left to right instead of top to bottom.  Here is the similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925157/css-columns-with-left-right-flow

Can we make columns to flow from left to right?