# How to flow multi-column elements from left to right before top-down in css?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am working on a html code as shown below in which I want to align multi-column elements from left-right before top-down.

```
<ul class="list-tomorrow-page">
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page"></li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page"></li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page"></li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page"></li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page"></li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page"></li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page"></li>
</ul>

@media (min-width: 767px) {
.list-tomorrow-page {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 6rem;
}
}

@media (min-width: 767px)
.article-tomorrow-page {
    height: 475px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The above html code display the o/p in the following fashion:

```
item1  item5

item2  item6

item3  item7

item4
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what I should make in the css code above so that it displays the list of items in the following fashion:

```
item1    item2
item3    item4
item5    item6
item7
```

I copied the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481337/flow-multi-column-elements-left-right-before-top-down) but it didn't work.

```
<style>
  ul {list-style: none;}
  li {float: left;}
  li:nth-child(2n+1) {clear: left;} /* 1st of every twos */
</style>
```

Comment: Use flexbox, set a width for each item, and allow them to wrap.

Comment: @hungerstar I used flexbox but it doesn't wrap two items in a row. It wraps multiple items.

Comment: The solution you gave in the link does work https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/qe925bgd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple option would be to use flex with flex-wrap:

```css
.list-tomorrow-page {
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.article-tomorrow-page {
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-tomorrow-page">
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page">1</li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page">2</li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page">3</li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page">4</li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page">5</li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page">6</li>
   <li class="article-tomorrow-page">7</li>
</ul>
```